# Support 'oneOf' keyword in pactflow

Tags: code-contracts, contract, pact-broker, pactflow

I have a question regarding keyword support oneOf in the schema...Using BDCT workflow and we have oneOf  keyword in the schema and I had followed the instructions here : https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/bi-directional-contract-testing/contracts/oas/keyword-support/ and we did dereferencing and inlining $refs with keyword oneOf pact results are red and without oneOf pact results are green.
Can we use oneOf keyword in schema to make pact green? Any suggestions?
Please refer to the attached observations.